# serverless update check failed error

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, npm, serverless

I want to intsall serverless on my kali linux . In order to proceed for serverless installalation we need node js install , which i have already done .

```
root@gpunk:~# npm --version
3.10.10
root@gpunk:~# node --version
v6.10.0
root@gpunk:~# nvm --version
0.31.0
```

(Some solutions on github suggested to install node js by nvm to solve this issue , tried that as well..) .
now when i run the command to `npm install -g serverless` to install serverless , i get following error message .

```
root@gpunk:~# npm install -g serverless
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/serverless -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/slss -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/sls -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless

> serverless@1.24.1 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js


┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│          serverless update check failed           │
│        Try running with sudo or get access        │
│       to the local update config store via        │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /root/.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib
`-- serverless@1.24.1
```

What possible mistake am i making , and how to overcome it ??

Comment: similar issue is been posted here it might helpful, https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4452

Comment: From there only i got idea about nvm and i tried that too....

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Better not install `serverless` as a global dependency. You can include as a project dependency instead.

Comment: "Try running with sudo"

Answer (score 17):

I've had a similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04. The issue was an optional postinstall script that failed.

I found the solution to be as follows:

```
npm install -g try-thread-sleep
npm install -g serverless --ignore-scripts spawn-sync
```

Source: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4319